# Scala strange type error in Play Framework form

Tags: scala, playframework

I have this code:

```
package deliveries.NewPost
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._

case class NewPostValidator(town: String, number: Int)

object NewPost extends Delivery{
  def form[NewPostValidator](): Form[NewPostValidator] = Form(mapping(
    "town" -> nonEmptyText,
    "number" -> number)(NewPostValidator.apply)(NewPostValidator.unapply))
}
```

At compile time it gives me strange error:

> type mismatch; [error]  found   :
>   play.api.data.Mapping[deliveries.NewPost.NewPostValidator] [error] 
>   required: play.api.data.Mapping[NewPostValidator]

Basically the same class shows with full path and without full path.
What can it be?

I will clarify what I'm trying to achieve:
I want every class extending trait to have method "form" that returns Form with some validator in it. For this I've created trait:

```
trait Delivery {
  def form[T](): Form[T]
}
```

and trying to implement this method in my class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying `def form[NewPostValidator]` is like saying `def form[T]`, just with a different identifier. Compiler doesn't see the NewPostValidator in the method body as the "real" NewPostValidator, but as your made-up type NewPostValidator that you declared in `def form[NewPostValidator]`.

Solution:

Parameterize your trait with [T] instead of your method, and have your class extend the trait with a specific type.

```
trait Delivery[T] {
  def form(): Form[T]
}

object NewPost extends Delivery[NewPostValidator] {
  def form(): Form[NewPostValidator] = Form(mapping(
    "town" -> nonEmptyText,
    "number" -> number)(NewPostValidator.apply)(NewPostValidator.unapply))
}
```

Comment: Thanks @slouc. You are right. What I'm trying to do is to make function compatible with trait where this function is def form[T](): Form[T] So, I need this [NewPostValidator] part but can't understand how to make it work

Comment: If the method in that trait is `def form[T](): Form[T]` and you are extending it (and therefore you need to implement method form), then the method needs to retain the same signature. What you did has an effect of simply renaming "T" to "NewPostValidator". If you want to "specialize" the method to work not for any T, but just NewPostValidator, then it's not the same function any more (meaning, if you're implementing or overriding the method `def form[T](): Form[T] ` then you have to use that same signature; you can't just narrow it down to work only for NewPostValidator).

Comment: Try explaining your problem in more details with providing more code (including that trait). You now know why your attempt doesn't work, but I can't tell you how to achieve what you're trying to achieve since I don't have the full picture. For example, here's another thing you can do - if you are the author of that trait, move the [T] from method parameter to class parameter, e.g. trait Foo[T], and then have your class extend Foo[NewPostValidator]. This way the methods can have signatures `def form(): Form[T]` and `def form(): Form[NewPostValidator]` respectively.

Comment: Thanks @slouc I have clarified my original question. I've got my mistake but understand how to achieve what I want correctly.

Comment: Actually your suggestion moving parameter to class does work. But is it possible to use parameter in function?

Comment: I edited my answer. Type parameter in a function is merely a placeholder, parameterizing with concrete type doesn't make sense.